# Reinstall SpreadsheetGear on new server

Tags: spreadsheetgear

We use SpreadsheetGear with c# scripts.
Currently it's installed on Windows 2008 R2. We need to move it to another server running Windows 2016. How do I go about the installation so that our scripts keep running without interruption.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to *install* SpreadsheetGear on a server.  SpreadsheetGear is a component / library for .NET developers, so you would typically be adding a reference to one or more SpreadsheetGear assemblies in your own Visual Studio Projects, then build and deploy your own entire application to whatever location you need, such as a new server.

If you are using the SpreadsheetGear for .NET Framework product, it is distributed *as installers* from the SpreadsheetGear website (see the [Licensed User Downloads](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/downloadlicensed.aspx) page), but these installers are intended to be run on a developer's machine (it provides samples, documentation, integration with Visual Studio).  You should not be installing these directly on a server.

If you are using the SpreadsheetGear for .NET Standard product, then this is distributed as the [SpreadsheetGear package on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/spreadsheetgear/), and you'd simply add a reference to it within whatever Visual Studio Projects require it.